# Notification to android app by sql server data changing

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications

My application is connected to the server database and the bank check date is recorded in the database. I would like to issue an alert in my app at checkout time to pay for the account. How do I real-time notify even when the app is completely closed?

Comment: You can use FCM push notification to your application from server

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran I don't want to use FCM. is there any other solution?

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran I use from SignalR but the problem is that SignalR connection closed after closed application

Comment: You can use Socket communication, but you cant use that in Background in the latest Android versions, If you want to use in background then we should use the Foreground service to run the socket in background. And I am not aware of SignalIR, But I feel you can think of FCM in worst case it will solve your problem.